# How do I connect to another player's world in Minecraft Pocket Edition 11.1?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I updated my Minecraft to 11.1 and I want to join my cousin's world but it is just giving me the message 'invalid name'

What do I do?

Comment: Why would it say this? Are you on Minecraft PE?

Comment: @TheCodingMonster - He is, I didn't notice the tag. Fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a space in your name? I had a space and it wouldn't let me use it. I had to change it.

Answer (score 0):

take out any spaces or special characters

Answer (score -2):

You can't have a made up name you need your real name

Comment: I'm pretty sure it requires your gamecenter/google+ username not your real life name.